# Android ViewPager onOverScrolled

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

Is it possible to get the onOverScrolled event on a ViewPager?
With a ScrollView you can override that method but ViewPager does not inherit from ScrollView directly. There's only a OnPageChangeListener, but that one does not provide information about overscrolling.

Comment: If you can determine how many pages you want to display, then why you require overscrolling? You can get the current page you are displaying and you can determine the last one.

Comment: I like to trigger a certain event when the user tries to scroll over the last page.

Comment: The method "onPageScrolled (int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)" might help you. If there are any page then as per the indication the position will have position+1. By comparing with current position, do what you want to do in that. Hope this will help.

Comment: I got it working using onPageScrolled and counting the number of events with the maximum possible offset. As the user keeps overscrolling, the callback is repeatedly invoked with that offset and I can trigger an action after a certain number of repeats. Thank you for having me look at that method again!

Comment: Welcome. Please press up arrow button on left side of the comment so it will be useful for others.